# Show hover effect when entering a page

Tags: css

my menu bar at the bottom of my page is triggered by an hover effect of a logo, which also has an 1sec delay on mouseout.
I want to see the menu when i enter a page for 1sec. So the user can see how you can open the menu.

Cheers Jasper

Comment: And we're supposed to guess at the code you have?

Comment: If you want people to answer, you will need to specify the question, and add your codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead of doing it by using `:hover` in your css (I will assume that that is how you are doing it...) using JavaScript to add and remove a class on hover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // event hover add / remove open class
    $("#menu").on("mouseenter", function(e){
        $(e.currentTaget).addClass('open');
    }).on("mouseleave", function(){
        $(e.currentTaget).removeClass('open');
    });
    // hide menu 5s after page load
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(e.currentTaget).removeClass('open');
    }, 5000);
});
```

When the page load your menu will have the `class` open by default.

```
<div id="#menu" class="open">
    <!-- menu items... -->
</div>
```

Then in your css use:

```
#menu {
    /* menu close style */
}

#menu .open {
    /* menu open style */
}
```

Hope it helps :)